# Distorted images when using ImageList on ToolStripButton

Tags: c#, .net, toolstrip, toolstripbutton

I want to put some images into a `ToolStripButton`, and have the images change depending on the state of the button.

So I've set the `.ImageList` of the `ToolStrip` to be my `ImageList` and simply change the `ToolStripButton.ImageIndex` to the appropriate value.

However, the icons appear distorted in comparison to providing exactly the same picture directly to the `ToolStripButton.Image` property.

In the picture below the image on the left hand side is the one from the `ImageList`, the one on the right is being set through `ToolStripButton.Image`. As you can see, the one on the left has some small odd pixels, specially visible when the button is selected.

I've tried modifying the `TransparencyColor` and `ColorDepth` but that's not made any difference. Any clues as to what I'm missing?

[image: Odd icons]

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `AutoSize` to `false` and `ImageScaling`  to `ToolStripItemImageScaling.None`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, neither worked though.

Answer (score 0):

You can put pictures in Resources and replace `ImageList` with `Dictionary`? In this case, pictures will be equal to the original.

```
Dim dictPictures As New Dictionary(Of String, Bitmap)
Dim runTimeResourceSet As Object
Dim dictEntry As DictionaryEntry
runTimeResourceSet = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, True, True)
For Each dictEntry In runTimeResourceSet
    If (dictEntry.Value.GetType() Is GetType(Bitmap)) Then
        If Not dictPictures.ContainsKey(dictEntry.Key & ".png") Then dictPictures.Add(dictEntry.Key & ".png", dictEntry.Value)
    End If
Next
```

P.S. Code is in `VB.NET` but you'll get the point.